# Error during Drupal installation: MySQL support not included in PHP

Tags: installation, mysql

[image]

I am getting an error as show by the image above when attempting to install CiviCRM on drupal.

What does this error message mean and how could I go about fixing it?

The entire configuration report is as follows:

[image]

Comment: check out this comment https://www.drupal.org/node/61810#comment-119083

Comment: This link is out of date. I have similar problem encounter today with civicrm

Comment: I have php-5.6.31. Still giving the same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recommend **setting MAMP to use PHP5.6** if you have that option.

The screenshots show MAMP is set to use PHP7, but [CiviCRM isn't ready for PHP7 yet](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17789).

(PHP7 [removes `ext/mysql`](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7) in favour of `ext/mysqli` and `ext/pdo_mysql`. CiviCRM looks for `ext/mysql`, and the installer test is bailing out when it detects that this isn't supported.)

[CiviCRM's PHP requirements are documented in the CiviCRM wiki.](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+PHP+Requirements)

Comment: CiviCRM's wiki actually shows PHP5.4 as "recommended" currently, but I think that's just an out of date doc as 5.4 is [no longer a supported version of PHP](http://php.net/supported-versions.php). I'll update the wiki to mention PHP7.

Answer (score 1):

its worth noting that now with the release of 4.7.12 and the work completed on [CRM-17789](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17789) That you now have 2 options,

1. Download the later code base that does support php7
2. Downgrade PHP to 5.6 as suggested by Chris

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the DSN in civicrm.settings.php from mysql to mysqli in the following line:
define( 'CIVICRM_UF_DSN', 'mysql**i**://cms_db_username:cms_db_password@db_server/cms_database?new_link=true');

Comment: Suggest doing this only if you intend helping work on [CRM-17789](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17789). If you intend to *use* CiviCRM, use a supported PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this problem, XAMPP 5.5.33 is shipping with the mysql_connect extension disabled by default. You need to go to php.ini file and uncomment  the line

;;extension=php_mysql.dll