# MySQL support not included in PHP - Wordpress Heroku

Tags: wordpress, php

Got this error on heroku wordpress with ClearDB Mysql Connected. Everything works expect this:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CiviCRM [installer checks for the presence of `mysql_connect`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/install/index.php#L348). Your Heroku environment has `mysql_*` extension disabled. The installer won't run if the environment doesn't pass CiviCRM's checks (as you've discovered).

This mysql_ library was [deprecated in PHP5.5 and removed in PHP7](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). It looks like Heroku do offer `mysql_` as an option you can enable through composer.json (see their docs on [Heroku PHP extension support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions)).

Even so, it's likely easier to use a hosting environment known to support CiviCRM; if you're a CiviCRM pioneer on Heroku, you may have to deal with other features of that environment which CiviCRM hasn't been road-tested with. (Not a criticism of Heroku - but CiviCRM has some expectations of its host environment above and beyond the "average" PHP app.)

It's also possible that you could convert CiviCRM to use `mysqli_*` with a global replace of the `mysql_*` functions through the CiviCRM codebase ... if that works, the relevant ticket is [CRM-16067: Replace deprecated mysql api with PDO or mysqli](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16067)!

See also:

- [Undefined function mysql_connect on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108087/call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect-on-heroku-php-works-fine-locally-bu)
- [Error during Drupal installation: MySQL support not included in PHP](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9276/error-during-drupal-installation-mysql-support-not-included-in-php)
- [php.net: mysql deprecation](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation)