# Issue with MySQL support

Tags: php, mysql

Attempting to install CiviCRM 4.6.38 in Wordpress 4.9.8, PHP 7.2.5, MariaDB 10.3.8, Nginx 1.14.0, Amazon Linux 2. Getting "MySQL support not included in PHP". PHPinfo shows mysqli and mysqlnd enabled.

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM 4.6 is not compatible with PHP7.2 - you'll either need to upgrade CiviCRM, or downgrade PHP. (CiviCRM 4.6 is quite an old release to install in 2018.)

CiviCRM runs [this check](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/install/index.php#L438) when installing (here's [the same check in 4.6](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.6/install/index.php#L536)).

If the server's PHP does not have the appropriate function ([`mysqli_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) in recent CiviCRM, compatible with your PHP7.2, and [`mysql_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) in CiviCRM 4.6 - suitable for older PHP releases only as it was deprecated in PHP5.5 and removed in PHP7.0), then the installer will bail out saying that you "lack MySQL support in your PHP".

If you want to use CiviCRM 4.6, you'll need to run it with an older version of PHP.

I recommend **using a current and supported version of both CiviCRM and PHP** instead.

- [CiviCRM: What version should I get?](https://civicrm.org/versions)
- [PHP: Supported versions](http://php.net/supported-versions.php)
- [2016 SE question that's similar](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9276/error-during-drupal-installation-mysql-support-not-included-in-php)
- [2016 CiviCRM blog post about the switch from mysql to mysqli](https://civicrm.org/blog/totten/psa-please-verify-php-extension-mysqli)